# glassfish updatetool doesen't start

Tags: jakarta-ee, windows-8, glassfish

I'm trying to follow the Java EE 6 Tutorial and I'm getting some problems with the updatetool application. I'm running it under Windows 8 but it simple doesen't start at all.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

JB

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Initially the firewall was turned off. then I did the following steps:

1. uninstalled python from my computer.
2. uninstalled the glassfish. (in my case I also deleted the folder : C:\glassfish4)
3. turn off the AVG antivirus protection (or if you have another antivirus, turn it off too)

started the JEE6 SDK installation again. 
everything worked then. hope this helps.